# adding unicode characters to database issue

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Hello iam really fighting to solve this problem

i have a script to insert arabic letters to database

my database and tables is utf-unicode_ci

```
$title = make_safe($_POST['title']);
$author = make_safe($_POST['author']);
$category = make_safe($_POST['category']);
$meta = str_replace(array('-', ' ', '*'),",",make_safe($_POST['meta']));
if ($title == "" OR $author == "" OR $category == "")
{
    echo $lang['STORY_FIELDS_MUST_FILL'];
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='2; URL= stories.php?action=add'>"; 
}
else 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare ("INSERT INTO stories (title,author,category,meta,date)
    VALUES (:title,:author,:category,:meta)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title,
                         ':author' => $author,
                         ':category' => $category,
                         ':meta' => $meta));
    echo "$lang[STORY_ADDED]";
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='2; URL=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "'>";
}
```

When adding the article From this php code it show in phpmyadmin like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQMag.jpg]

And when i insert values Via Phpmyadmin

it show like this and everything going fine

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohmlv.jpg]

How can i add it via php code to show same like adding it from phpmyadmin

Comment: So there must be some trick that `make_safe` is doing. If you can post that function too.

Comment: Do you execute 'SET names utf8' query when you connect to mysql?

Comment: `make_safe()` seems unnecessary

Comment: @Rikesh Its Only Add mysql_real_escape_string sorry i forget to remove it its unneccessary

Comment: @krcko This is my config file $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$namedb;charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks The Solution Is After Connect Code execute this

$pdo->exec('SET NAMES \'utf8\' COLLATE \'utf8_unicode_ci\'');